# How to format a date

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, string-formatting

I'd like to calculate the time difference between two dates, but I'm unable to parse a string representation of a date that looks like `2015-01-13 15:59:10`, for example, through a formatter `SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");`

Only string dates in the form, `String dateStart = "01/14/2012 09:29:58";`, for example work.

How should I go about parsing `2015-01-13 15:59:10`, for example through `SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");`?

Comment: SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your format needs to match the literal you're trying to parse:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

instead of

```
format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 2):

Your format must match your input string. The correct format is:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more details and an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

to parse `2015-01-13 15:59:10` you should change the date format to below:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

Answer (score 1):

SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")